# What is this marine creature? Is this a fossil?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology

Found this on a beach on the East coast of India - Vishakhapatnam, India

Is this a fossil? A coral?

[image]
Its small enough to fit in my hand
[image]
These tunnel-like structures are hard like rock/calcified
[image]
Obverse
[image]
Obverse

Comment: Doesn't look like a fossil because doesn't look rock-like enough and not buried. Maybe this? https://gohiking.ca/animals/fish/marine-worms/calcareous-tube-worm/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not a fossil.

It is just shells of various marine invertebrates that get stuck together as they grow. It looks like worm-snails on a a large piece of clam shell. the little holes in the clam shell are bored by sea snails and erosion.

[image]

there are whole blogs devoted to finding interesting examples. https://natureinfocus.blog/2010/01/13/calcareous-worm-tubes-on-flat-oyster-shells/